# What charging pads are compatible with Verizon's HTC 8X?

Tags: htc, charging, htc-8x

The Verizon version of the HTC 8X supports inductive charging. However, I could not find a charging pad on Verizon's website, and Verizon Support told me that they don't sell the pads. Where can I buy a compatible inductive charging pad?

Comment: I think you should change your question to "What charging pads are compatible" since "Where can I buy" could lead to unwanted advertising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the Verizon HTC Windows Phone 8X also supports the Qi charging standard (compare: http://www.zdnet.com/nokia-lumia-920-or-htc-windows-phone-8x-a-purchase-made-with-the-head-instead-of-the-heart-7000007211/).

So you can buy any Qi compatible charging pad (like e.g. the Nokia or Blackberry ones) in your favorite store.

Answer (score 1):

I purchased a pad called Samsung easy charge at Best Buy. It was for some Galaxies, not all, but it charges my Nokia Lumia 920 beautifully. I tried it at the store before buying. Best Buy does not deal with Windows phones so they don't sell the pads for Nokia, but this worked for me. My grandson has a Samsung Galaxy, and the charger did not work for his phone.

Comment: Any Qi compatible wireless charger should work.